# Two practically identical event methods act differently

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a very strange behaviour in my app.
I've got this two methods:

```
public void OnItemLoaded(object source, ItemArgs e)
{
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Event triggered");
    NavigationPage newPage = new NavigationPage(new UrlView());
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(newPage);
}

void Handle_ItemSelected(object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    NavigationPage newPage = new NavigationPage(new UrlView());
    Navigation.PushModalAsync(newPage);
}
```

The first one is fired up by an event, and it does work, since the WriteLine shows up correctly, but doesn't navigate to the page.
The second one is just a test for me, it's triggered by a click on an item of a listview and loads up as expected.
They are both on the same page and nothing is different except the way they are triggered.
If I use:

`Application.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new UrlView());`

It does work, but I lose the ability to go back to previous page by pressing the back button, and the modal behaviour. I thought of using:

`Navigation.InsertPageBefore(new TabsPage(), this);`

On the page I load, but then I get:

"Exception : before must be in the pushed stack of the current context"

I'm thinking of inserting manually a back button on screen but it feels nonsensical...

I'm totally stuck at this point.
Any idea?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: If you use the `async` method, be sure to call `await`. https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical/#Pushing_Pages_to_the_Navigation_Stack

Comment: Thanks, already tried with that, setting async public void OnItemLoaded and await Navigation.PushModalAsync, but to no avail... it just blinks for a split second and doesn't open the page, while, again, it works with the other method anyway.